# Setting fine-grained password policy on an OU - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, password-policy

I found this article: [AD DS Fine-Grained Password and Account Lockout Policy Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842%28v=ws.10%29) really useful to set fine-grained password policies for a user or a Security Group.

But I haven't found any way to do this at an OU level - at least not any way that I can get it to work.

Any good articles that show how to do this?

Comment: Did you miss this statement in that article?  **PSOs cannot be applied to organizational units (OUs) directly.**

Comment: Me bad. I dived right in to Step 1!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot apply FGPP to an OU directly.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(WS.10).aspx

Fine-grained password policy cannot be applied to an organizational unit (OU) directly. To apply fine-grained password policy to users of an OU, you can use a shadow group.

A shadow group is a global security group that is logically mapped to an OU to enforce a fine-grained password policy. You add users of the OU as members of the newly created shadow group and then apply the fine-grained password policy to this shadow group. You can create additional shadow groups for other OUs as needed. If you move a user from one OU to another, you must update the membership of the corresponding shadow groups.

Comment: Yep. Make a group. Put everyone in the OU that you want to target in that group. Done.