# Complex Password GPO Security Filtering Access Denied

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019

We are just trying to apply a password policy to a set of users of a security group, we've added the security group to the Security Filtering, but when running the Group Policy Modeling with a user that is the group it's getting denied.

The security group does have read and apply GPO set in the Delegation, the policy is set at the domain level and the link order is #1.  We've also tried adding the Domain Computers security group the the security filtering also with no avail.  When we remove the security group and just add back Authenticated Users it applies correctly to all users or when we have the authenticated users and the specific security group with authenticated users it applies to all users still, figured it may apply to least privilege, which doesn't appear to be the case :). Simulated having loopback processing applied as both replace and merge in the modeling, no luck. More than happy to apply screen shots of setup if needed for assistance.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Ronnie

Comment: Are you trying to implement a fine-grained password policy?

Comment: I agree with Joe. Had similar wishes from customers. only with a fine grained police will it be possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting fine-grained password policy on an OU - Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/403176/setting-fine-grained-password-policy-on-an-ou-windows-server-2008)